# Sprite Kit: How to pass scores between different scene?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am stuck trying to pass the score between two scenes, MyScene, and MyMenu.
The game part where the score changes is declared as _score(NSInteger), and its label is _scoreLabelNode(SKLabelNode) the code that I used to Initalize the label, and create the label that holds the score in MyScene is

```
_score = 0;
_scoreLabelNode = SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"MarkerFelt-Wide;
_scoreLabelNode.position =CGPointMake (CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 3 *self.frame.size.height /4);
_scoreLabelNode.zPosition = 100;
_scoreLabelNode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_score];
_scoreLabelNode.fontColor =[UIColor blackColor];
[self addChild:_scoreLabelNode]
```

So I guess my question is, How do I transfer the score between the two scenes when the score needs to change in MyScene, and needs to show the score the user got in MyMenu. Thanks in advance.

PS:I'm Just learning code so I would appreciate a detailed response

Answer (score 1):

Use NSUserDefaults like so in MyScene:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setInteger:_score forKey:@"score"];
```

And in MyMenu:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int score = [prefs integerForKey:@"score"];
SKLabelNode *scoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"MarkerFelt-Wide"];
//Other label node configuration here
scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score]
//Other configuration here
```

This might not be quite right, wrote it off the top of my head. Xcode will help you fix any warnings/errors.

Comment: where do i put each of the code?in interface or implementation?

Comment: I put both in the implementation part in the .m's of each file. This is resulting in the Same thing as before. The score says 0 no matter what I get. Was I supposed to delete the _scoreLabelNode code in each? and should I delete the _, and the Node in _scoreLabelNode considering the SKLabelNode you wrote was scoreLabel? Do I have to declare anything in the interface?

Comment: i agree with @nathreed. On app launch (in app delegate didFinishLaunching method) you might want to set the score to 0 if userDefaults value returns nil. Then when your menu appears you can update your score by getting the user default value. You will have to add to the user default value in MyScene

Comment: @JoelBalmer  is there anyway you could share that code with me? Thanks

Comment: Technically this approach will work, but I don't think this is really the intended use of NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the MyMenu scene's `userData` property.

```
 - (void) goToMenuScene
 {
      SKView *spriteView = (SKView *) self.view;
      SKScene *newScene = [[MyMenu alloc]initWithSize:self.size];

      NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]
      [dic setInteger:_score forKey:@"score"];
      newScene.userData = dic;

      [spriteView presentScene:newScene];

 }
```

At the point you want to present the scene, call

```
[self goToMenuScene];
```

And in the MyMenu scene,

```
int score = [[self.userData objectForKey:@"score"]intValue];
```

Comment: I am getting the "Use of undeclared identifier 'goToMenuScene'" in MyScene and "No visible interface for 'NSMutableDictionary' declares the selector 'integerForKey" in MyMenu

Comment: how are you calling the method? you need to write [self goToMenuScene];

Comment: which one? the void or the int

Comment: Yes, essentially, thats what you have to do. Try it out and see for yourself. Experiment. That's how you learn.

Comment: okay, I have pasted the -(void)goToMenuScene code into MyScene.m In addition, I pasted the self goToMenueScene code. In MyMenum, I have pasted the int score line. The errors I am getting are use of undeclared identifier goToMenuScene(from MyScene) and a notification of Unused variable 'score' @akashg

Comment: Where are you getting the "use of undeclared identifier" error? I think you are calling the method incorrectly. As for the unused variable warning, you will lose that as soon as you use the score variable in the code

Comment: it says that -(void) goToMenuScene is using the undeclared identifier of goToMenuScene

Comment: Are you sure you have not added the method in another method?

Comment: Great catch. However, the new errors i am getting are "No known class method for selector 'scene' on the SKSCENE *newScene = MyMenu scene];     In addition, I am getting "No visible interface for 'NSMutable' declares the selector'setInteger:ForKey:'" on the nextScene.userData line (all errors are in MyScene)

Comment: ^^ im not sure if I tagged you sorry

Comment: check the edited answer. I am sorry it's just that I am just writing the code off the top of my head

Comment: on the [dic setInteger:_score forKey:@"score"]; line i am getting a "no visible interface for 'NSMutableDictionary' declares the selector 'setInteger:forKey" what am i supposed to declare it as?

Answer (score 0):

I would setup my score in the app delegate upon launch with something like

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
     //SETUP SCORE
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
     NSInteger *score = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"hasAnsweredQuestion"];
     if (!score) {
          //SET SCORE AS nathreed SUGGESTS
     }
```

But equally you can just check if there is a score every time in the menuViewController

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I like akashg's answer, but here is an alternate way to do it which is even simpler.

You could declare a score property MyMenu.h file.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int score;
```

Then, in your MyScene.m file...

```
- (void) goToMyMenuScene
{
    SKScene *myMenuScene = [[MyMenu alloc]initWithSize:self.size];
    myMenuScene.score = _score;
    [self.view presentScene:myMenuScene];
}
```